# Show upload button for IFormFile inside model in Swashbuckle 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger-ui, aspnetboilerplate, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I'm using Swashbuckle v5 for creating a web UI to show my service.

When I use a model with multiple properties and different datatypes, I want to show an upload button for each `IFormFile` property inside that model.

When my model is like this:

```
public async Task InsertFileByAdmin(IFormFile formFile)
{
     ...
}
```

everything is ok and Swagger shows an upload button.

[image]

But for this model that has 2 `IFormFile`s:

```
public class CreateDeviceDto
{
    public string OwnerFirstName { get; set; }

    public string OwnerLastName { get; set; }

    public IFormFile ImageUpload { get; set; }

    public IFormFile IconUpload { get; set; }
}
```

my Swagger UI shows `IFormFile` as a string property.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Add `[HttpPost]` and `[Consumes("multipart/form-data")]` to your method:

```cs
[HttpPost]
[Consumes("multipart/form-data")]
public async Task CreateDevice(CreateDeviceDto input)
```